# Get value from CompositeDisposable RXJava - Android

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

How can I get return value from bellow code :

```
CompositeDisposable mCompositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
        mCompositeDisposable.add(observableSubject(userName, password)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnSubscribe(new Consumer<Disposable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(@NonNull Disposable disposable) throws Exception {
                    }
                })
                .doFinally(new Action() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() throws Exception {
                    }
                })
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(String res) {
                        //I need to get value from out of mCompositeDisposable.add(...)
                        Log.i("LOG", res);
                    }
                }));
```

And :

```
private Observable<String> observableSubject(String userName, String password) {
    return Observable.defer(() -> {
        //Some Code
        return Observable.just("Value");
    });
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the value received in `onNext` within `onNext`?

Comment: need to get value from out of mCompositeDisposable.add(...)

Comment: That's not possible and even makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem with `EventBus` in this method :

```
@Override
public void onNext(String res) {
   //SomeCode .... 
   //.... EventBus.getDefault() ....
}
```

Comment: That makes even less sense and defeats the purpose of RxJava. Whatever is listening on the other end of that event bus, pull it inside `onNext`.